# powershell Get-Process MainWindowTitle

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication

On Windows I have a running Process with a `MainWindowTitle`.

| Process name | Name | MainWindowTitle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACDBServ.exe | Acron Database Server | Acron Database Server on Port: **** |

[process with MainWindowTitle (Task-Manager)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMRQS.png)

To show the MainWindowTitle
i have the following power shell code:

```bash
    #search all processes with processName
    $foundProcess = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name.Equals($processName) }

    foreach ($process in $foundProcess) {
      $outputString += "MainWindowTitle: $($process.MainWindowTitle)`n"
    }
```

If I execute the powershell as admin user(`PC\Administrator`) the title is given back correct:
`MainWindowTitle: ACRON Database Server on...`

If i let run the script from my service with the following standard user:
`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`
The main `MainWindowTitle` field is empty.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the `MainWindowTitle` from process with the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user?

Comment: It seems to be related to the task scheduler. Even when running the task as the same local administrator certain properties (CommandLine, MainWindowTitle, StartInfo, ...) are different.